# Checking message.content in Discord.py if a member name is in the message

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a function in my Discord.py bot where I am trying to check if one of the parameters in the command is the name of a member.

here is the code:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, *, message):
    x = message.guild.members
    for member in x:
        if member.name in message.content:
            print(member.name)
```

for example: `$test John Tom Alice`
should print in the console:

 John

 Tom

 Alice

I have tried this however this error keeps popping up:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'guild'

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message variable is a string of its contents so you can't call it for the guild members. What you're looking for is the context (ctx).

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, *, message):
for member in ctx.guild.members:
    if member.name in message:
        print(member.name)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have tried to use this code however, an error is shown in the console. Here it is:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content' 

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'

Comment: Did you by any chance write `message.content` instead of `message`?

Comment: I did indeed. My bad, your code works now. Thank you for helping out! How does this work though? What does `.content` do? (forgive my inexperience, I'm new to python butI'm more fluent in Java)

Comment: `.content` is not a build-in function of Python, so I understand some confusion. The `.content` applies to a message object from discord.py and our message variable is not a message object, but rather a string. So if you wanted to use `.content` you would need a message object. An example of a message obect would be in an `on_message` event.

Answer (score -2):

You have to check your "message" argument. Based on your error, "message" is considered as str variable. So "message" variable won't have guild as member.

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, *, message):
    if not hasattr(message,'guild'):
        raise Exception(f'`message` is not valid argument')
    x = message.guild.members
    for member in x:
        if member.name in message.content:
            print(member.name)
```